# hide folder (.git) in a shared server from all other users

Tags: server, permissions, git

I am working in a server shared by several other users. There is a particular folder for us to put our project datasets in e.g.

```
/userAdataset1
/userBdataset1
/mydataset1
/mydataset2
```

My datasets have some scripts in it that I would like to sync across the different servers (through github). If I `git init` in the folder I will get a `.git` file like so

```
.git    
/userAdataset1
/userBdataset1
/mydataset1
/mydataset2
```

How can I hide that file from others and what happens if someone else also creats a `.git` folder? An alternative would simply be for me to create the `.git` folder in each of my dataset but I was just wondering if there is a way to do what I am asking above.

Comment: That's not the way to do it. Indeed you would have to create a git repository inside each separate dataset, unless you want to manage all datasets of all users with one repository.

Comment: @Sebastian thank you. That is what I eventually did. I created a git repository in each dataset.